# Google Play services missing or without correct permission and other mistakes permanently crushes my blanc app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, genymotion

I`ve got this error on genymotion, android studio & vs code (blanc expo app). Adding full logs from logcat. My app crushes immediately after opening. Adb now is working, added some path variables. Finally it starts attempts to open, but have several mistakes. Google play is not the last error, what you could see from my logs.

```
2021-09-26 16:17:00.106 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.331 5359-5386/host.exp.exponent E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.528 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent I/FacebookInitProvider: Failed to auto initialize the Facebook SDK
        A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
            at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:39)
            at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:9)
            at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:1)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.528 5359-5377/host.exp.exponent I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 22048
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.528 5359-5377/host.exp.exponent I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.546 5359-5377/host.exp.exponent I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
          adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app host.exp.exponent
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.759 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.838 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent E/f: Failed to clear legacy OkHttp cache
        java.io.IOException: not a readable directory: /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/okhttp
            at okhttp3.internal.io.FileSystem$1.deleteContents(FileSystem.java:7)
            at okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache.delete(DiskLruCache.java:2)
            at okhttp3.Cache.delete(Cache.java:1)
            at host.exp.exponent.u.f.b(ExponentNetwork.java:4)
            at host.exp.exponent.u.f.<init>(ExponentNetwork.java:7)
            at host.exp.exponent.q.a.<init>(NativeModuleDepsProvider.java:7)
            at host.exp.exponent.q.a.c(NativeModuleDepsProvider.java:2)
            at j.a.a.b.<init>(Exponent.java:7)
            at j.a.a.b.m(Exponent.java:2)
            at host.exp.exponent.i.onCreate(ExpoApplication.java:9)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.882 5389-5389/? W/dex2oat: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.885 5389-5389/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --dex-file=/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/audience_network.dex --oat-fd=33 --oat-location=/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/app_optimized/audience_network.dex --compiler-filter=speed
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.885 5389-5389/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.896 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: init start
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.896 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /vendor/lib
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.896 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /system/lib
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.897 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/host.exp.exponent-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.897 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/host.exp.exponent/lib-main flags = 1]
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.897 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.900 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/vendor/lib flags = 2]
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.900 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/host.exp.exponent-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.900 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/host.exp.exponent/lib-main flags = 1]
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.902 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/lib-main
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.903 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/lib-main regeneration interrupted: wiping clean
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.904 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: deps mismatch on deps store: regenerating
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.904 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: so store dirty: regenerating
    2021-09-26 16:17:00.975 5359-5386/host.exp.exponent E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.099 5359-5377/host.exp.exponent W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: host.exp.exponent requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.099 5359-5377/host.exp.exponent W/FA: Service invalid
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.169 5359-5359/host.exp.exponent A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xea6c84f3 in tid 5359 (st.exp.exponent)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.219 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.1.1/NMF26Q/76:userdebug/test-keys'
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG: pid: 5359, tid: 5359, name: st.exp.exponent  >>> host.exp.exponent <<<
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG: signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xea6c84f3
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000008  ebx eacfbb7c  ecx 00000004  edx 00000008
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     esi 12e77640  edi 12e71710
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.220 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     eip ea6c84f9  ebp ffd58ff8  esp ffd58fc0  flags 00010287
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 001084f9  /system/lib/libart.so (__memcmp16+1193)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00431496  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror6String9CompareToEPS1_+70)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00451e8f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL16String_compareToEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_+79)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 005b115c  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x520000) (java.lang.String.compareTo+136)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00109262  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00112d9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+237)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0031d646  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+294)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 003154e7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+615)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0067f007  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+535)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000ff2a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+29857)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 002e5f48  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.323 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 002ed6a0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+176)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.324 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0066d199  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1049)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.324 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0010f39d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.324 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 006ec411  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x520000) (java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort+477)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.324 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 006f0dc5  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x520000) (java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort+497)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.324 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 006c88c2  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x520000) (java.util.Arrays.sort+78)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.324 5396-5396/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00005bf4  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.324 580-601/system_process I/Choreographer: Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.514 5389-5399/? W/dex2oat: Class com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.87 failed lock verification and will run slower.
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.514 5389-5399/? W/dex2oat: Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
    2021-09-26 16:17:01.514 5389-5399/? W/dex2oat: and incorrect proguard optimizations.
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.173 580-5404/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity host.exp.exponent/.experience.HomeActivity
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.177 580-598/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.249 580-980/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process host.exp.exponent (pid 5359) has died
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.249 580-980/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 5359
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.249 288-288/? I/Zygote: Process 5359 exited due to signal (4)
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.251 580-596/system_process I/libprocessgroup: Killing pid 5389 in uid 10068 as part of process group 5359
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.256 580-596/system_process I/libprocessgroup: Killing pid 5389 in uid 10068 as part of process group 5359
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.262 580-596/system_process I/libprocessgroup: Killing pid 5389 in uid 10068 as part of process group 5359
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.268 580-596/system_process I/libprocessgroup: Killing pid 5389 in uid 10068 as part of process group 5359
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.273 580-596/system_process I/libprocessgroup: Killing pid 5389 in uid 10068 as part of process group 5359
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.278 580-596/system_process I/libprocessgroup: Killing pid 5389 in uid 10068 as part of process group 5359
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.282 580-1832/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.282 580-1832/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.283 580-1832/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.283 580-1832/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.288 580-601/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: goldfish_dma_create_region: could not obtain fd to device! fd -1 errno=2
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.326 580-1832/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xc8dc73c0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
    2021-09-26 16:17:02.493 605-1834/? E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (4 threads) starved for 163 ms
    2021-09-26 16:17:03.017 1205-1285/com.android.launcher3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: can you share your app.json Android section, If I can help you

Comment: Sorry, was busy...
if I have understood you clearly, that`s my app.json - it is very small) 

{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "displayName": "AwesomeProject"
}